# Why my bootstrap sass has no gutter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm using a fixed `container`, and bootstrap is supposed to have a 20px gutter on all sides.
Still, I'm getting no gutter, While Michael Hartl's layout is OK.

```
Mine                           |           Hartl's
```

[image: Mine] . [image: Hartl's]

I'm using Chrome on Linux.
Thanks!

### EDIT: Found the criminal: But now what?

```
/* line 9, /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bootstrap-sass-2.0.2/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_scaffolding.scss */
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #333333;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: You have to use the console of google chrome to check. You should have a css property in one of your css files which overwrite the bootstrap css.

Comment: I've checked, but couldn't see one - or  i just don't know which

Comment: Did you check body, html... ?

Comment: @Sebastien Indeed in one of the body rules. see my edit pls

Comment: You probably have to read the doc. I think you have a bad html structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using a custom style - but didn't solve the bootstrap problem (I'm only overriding it)

```
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Kudos to [Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/809953/sebastien) and [Terry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/803739/terry)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `.container-fluid`?

```
.container-fluid {
   padding-right: 20px;
   padding-left: 20px;
}
```

From example http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html

Comment: I'm using a fixed layout `.container`

Comment: incorporated your answer. +1.